# My custom font with an extended character set gets messed up when I convert it for for @font-face

Tags: fonts, font-face

I have been making a custom font that as well as having the alphabet and punctuation, also contains lots of icons. It's important to the project that they are in the same font file. I have been using an Latin extended 2 encoding to fit it all in. When i try and convert it with Font Squirrel or font2web it drops half of the character set - despite me specifying the encoding in the advanced options.

Font squirrel does mention in its documentation that it wont convert many extended characters.

My questions are: Is there a way to make FontSquirrel work properly? Could I be missing something? OR - how can i create these web font files (woff, eof etc) using software?

Thanks so much!

Caroline